# How to add subviews in custom camera?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have `UIView` which I am using as custom camera.
I need this camera for QRCode reading.

And I want to add subviews in that `UIView`. So is it possible to add subview to custom view used as camera.

I need camera like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you can add subview to any UIView object you want, just use addSubview: method  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:

Answer (score 1):

If your camer view is a custom subclasss of UIView, you can add other UIViews as it’s subviews